# How do I add Frameworks and Extensions to the new JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

So it looks like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)'s design has been updated. while i normally don't care in the old version there was a drop down under Frameworks and Extensions allowing you to select what external libraries you wanted such as one of many versions of Jquery. in this new version of the site this seems to have been removed.

looking at the docs page it appears to be explaining the old version so the [Frameworks and Extensions](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions) is no longer valid

Now i am wondering how does one add Frameworks and Extensions to a JSFiddle now that the entire section is gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with a fiddles to see when something is private and when something is public i found the HTML/CSS/Javascript labels in the top-right corners are actually buttons.

By clicking on the Javascript button you can see the Frameworks and Extensions section which used to be on the left side of the screen

[image: i thought it was weird that HTML/CSS/Javascript had a flower next to them]